# "Prompt Label" Custom Intent localization not working in iOS 17

Tags: swift, localization, widgetkit, ios17

I've an app with a custom intent to select a value from a list when configuring a widget. The prompt label (the title of the view controller presented where you can pick a value from a list) is localized (using the ID get from the XML when opening the widgetn intent definition). This translation works in iOS 16 (and lower) but in iOS 17 it shows always the text proivided in the "Prompt label".

I've not seen information about this... Anyone has this issue? Can it be a bug of the OS?